# Search for types with particular fields in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I have the following two docs

DOC 1

```
 { "name" : "Frank",
   "age" : 82
 }
```

DOC 2

```
 { "gender" : "male",
   "age" : 74
 }
```

How could I retrieve a list of documents that have `name` as a field, i.e. in the above (admittedly poor) example I would run some query that returns me the id for Doc 1 since that has `name`. If this is possible, I would then like to extend it so I could search for those docs that have `name` `AND` `age` as fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of the [exists filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-filter.html) and [bool filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html) to do this. You would essentially filter all the documents for those with the specified fields. An example is below.

```
{
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "name"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "age"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That seems to do it thanks. Is it possible to also check for the accompanying value, i.e. find all docs that have a field `name` that has the value `string`? 
Apologies, I should have investigated the filters first. It seems the [term filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html#query-dsl-term-filter) will do this

Comment: Yes the term filter will do that for you, as will the term query. If you're using the filter just remember that the results will be cached by default, so be aware of your memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use the exists filter?

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-filter.html

The following sample works for me.

```
PUT existsindex
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "number_of_shards": 1
  }
}

PUT existsindex/local/1
{
  "name":"Ian",
  "member":"yes"
}

PUT existsindex/local/2
{
  "name":"Roy"
}

GET existsindex/_search
{
  "filter": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "member"
    }
  }
}
```